# Round 2 decimals

Tags: php

I have an issue with php 5.6 rounding to two decimals. If you test the following it will export $y exactly as 19.620000000000001

I know there are solutions to display it using number_format, but how do I make it to be exactly 19.62?

Thanks.

```
$x = 19.620000000000001;
$y = round($x, 2);
var_export($y);
```

Later Edit.
I need it for exact math operations, not display.

Comment: reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You need to do some reading up on floating-point numbers.  One of the things that you need to learn first and foremost is there is no such thing as exact in floating point.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `echo` to display your output. It will give you your desired output

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `var_export`

Try using `echo` or `var_dump()`

```
$x = 19.620000000000001;
$y = round($x, 2);
echo $y;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$y = number_format($x, 2);
```

The `$y` will have 2 decimals but it will also be a string. Not sure if it's satisfactory.

Comment: @AlexandruRada you didn't say you need it for math operations. You said "to display it", but yeah, you probably can't casue it's a string, as I mentioned.